# Where is the AD group name stored in TFS 2008?

Tags: tfs, tfs-warehouse

The Team Foundation Server Administration Tool has a column called 'User' that contains the domain group that is being granted permissions to TFS. Searching through the TFSWarehouse table, I see the Person table, with the individual users, but can't find where the AD group name is stored. Is it in a TFS table? I'm looking to get a list of domain groups that have been allowed access to TFS.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the tbl_security_identity_cache table in the TfsIntegration database.  There should be a domain or account_name column in there that will have this data.

Comment: That has the domain, but not the AD group name that was added to the admin tool. By the way, the admin tool I'm referring to that has the domain group is from 'Power Toys for Visual Studio'.